# Make Cache.get(key, mappingFunction) fail all waiting threads too if mappingFunction fails in Caffeine

Tags: java, caching, guava, caffeine-cache

Make Cache.get(key, mappingFunction) fail all waiting threads too if mappingFunction fails in Caffeine

If 3 threads come in parallel then currently if first get call fail after 1 mins, then second fail after 2 mins, third in 3mins and so on.

I want if first get call fails then all waiting threads on get should also fail.

Comment: You could use AsyncCache which computes in a future as the mapping. It will remove a failed future automatically using a whenComplete action. The behavior you’re seeing is how ConcurrentHashMap’s computeIfAbsent works. The future approach instead lets the callers wait on a join while the value is being computed.

Comment: Tried with `buildAsync().synchronous()` and it worked. But can you please confirm if is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately a bit wasteful on threads until you can switch to virtual threads but it’s generally okay anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with buildAsync().synchronous() and it worked.
Thank you Ben Manes